# Некорректно пишутся записи в таблицу (функция count(*))

Tags: sql, sql-server

Запрос

```
INSERT INTO pre_load_log
(TABLE_NAME,
 RECORDS_CNT,
 CNT_DATE
)
       SELECT '[dbo].[Bus_Center]',
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM OPENQUERY(LS_ARDBPROD, 'select * from GW.Bus_Center') q
       ),
              SYSDATETIME();

TRUNCATE TABLE Bus_Center;

INSERT INTO dbo.Bus_Center
       SELECT *
       FROM OPENQUERY(LS_ARDBPROD, 'select * from GW.Bus_Center') q;

INSERT INTO load_log
(TABLE_NAME,
 RECORDS_CNT,
 CNT_DATE
)
       SELECT '[dbo].[Bus_Center]',
              @@rowcount,
              SYSDATETIME();
```

В результате в таблице `pre_load_log` в `RECORDS_CNT` = 200 записей а в `load_log` в `RECORDS_CNT` = 10000 записей.

Почему так произошло? По факту и там и там 1000 записей.

Comment: что такое *GW.Bus_Center* и *SGW.Bus_Center*? таблицы на связанном сервере?

Comment: GW и GW , там s была лишней.

Comment: Это linked server. причем одна и та же таблица в обоих случаях.